# cant retrieve relation from belongsToMany with different tablename

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I got the following tables:

```
| messages |   | likes      |
| id       |   | id         |
| content  |   | message_id |
               | user_id    |
```

I want to retrieve all the likes from a message.

Currently I've this relation on the `Message` model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\Like', 'likes', 'message_id', 'id');
}
```

But when I `dd(Message::find($id)->likes()->get()->toArray());` I get a exception:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'likes'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a has many relationship between `Message` model and `Like` model.

message.php

```
public function likes()
{
   return this->hasMany('App\Entities\Like');
}
```